# Special characters in ajaxcall

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble getting this AJAX call to work in IE11. I have some dropdowns showing types of cars (Manufacturer and model). The problem comes when I choose Citroën. It should show me the types of models, but it shows nothing. I guess it has something to do with the `ë` letter, but I can not get this script to work.

IE 11 writes this for Citroën: `CitroÃ « n`. I do have the UFT-8 in the header of the site and it works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. Can anybody see why?

```
$('#make').change(function(){
    $.post( "../ajaxmodelcar?model="+this.value, function( data ) {         
        $('#model').html(data);             
    });         
});
```

Comment: When you `POST` method, usually, you pass the data in the `data` argument of `$.post`. Passing a `data` in the URL is used, usually, with `GET`method. It does not answer the question, it's just an advice. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the value before you send it in the URL. You can either do this yourself using `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
$('#make').change(function(){
    $.post('../ajaxmodelcar?model=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value), function(data) {         
        $('#model').html(data);             
    });         
});
```

Or preferably you can provide an object to the `data` property of `$.post` and jQuery will encode it for you:

```
$('#make').change(function(){
    $.post('../ajaxmodelcar', { model: this.value }, function(data) {         
        $('#model').html(data);             
    });         
});
```